# Unable to set mac address to tap interface using systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, systemd, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to migrate some tap interfaces setup from `tunctl` to `systemd-networkd`. I'm using systemd version 215-8. So I have this `test.netdev` file:

```
[Match]

[NetDev]
Name=tap_test
Kind=tap
MACAddress=1:2:3:4:5:6
```

and a `test.network` file:

```
[Match]
Name=tap_test

[Network]
Description=tap interface
Address=1.2.3.4/24
```

This suppose to replace the command

```
ifconfig tap_test \
1.2.3.4 \
netmask  255.255.255.0 \
hw ether 1:2:3:4:5:6 up
```

which used to be run after the `tunctl` command.

The result is fine except for the fact that the MAC address was not configured correctly. In the documentation of systemd (**for 215 version**) it says that the MAC address should be configured in the `.netdev` file in the `[NETDEV]` section. (I know, in later versions of `systemd` the MAC adress is configured in matching `.network` files, but this isn't the case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [systemd.netdev(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#MACAddress=):

> The MAC address to use for the device. [...] This key is not currently suported for "tun" or "tap" devices.

According to [systemd commit e0fbf1fcffe014d5af6767b29f9108c2f2444888](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=e0fbf1fcffe014d5af6767b29f9108c2f2444888), this wasn't ever possible. As of systemd v215, this limitation *is not mentioned* in the manpage, which was an apparent documentation bug in that version.

Comment: do you know of any workaround to achieve the goal? To be more precise, do you know of a way to match a `.link`file to the `.netdev` device of type "tap" to do this configuration?

Comment: Doesn't matching on the name (`[Match] OriginalName=`) work? If not, then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tun/tap interface mac address with ip utility:

```
ip link set address {MAC_ADDR} dev {DEVICE}
```

Indeed, in case of migration to modern kernels it is suggested to use `iproute2` instead of `net-tools`, cause it uses rare `ioctl` instead of newer `netlink`.